# How can i read sessions saved in db with php?

Tags: php, session, yii

I have set Yii application session to save in database.

In one part of my app i need to read created session by Yii  but
i can't use `Yii::app()->session` because my code is out of Yii application.

Can i read this session with PHP function?

or

create and save **this specific** session with Yii in temp folder instead of database(so i can easily use `$_SESSION`)?

Comment: why would you need to access the database? Just use the session variables directly.

Comment: Why can't you simply move the code into Yii controller? Even if it is something specific, it's usually easy to work around.

Answer (score 1):

The function you're looking for is [`session_set_save_handler()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-set-save-handler.php).

This function allows you to override the default handling of the `$_SESSION` variable. You can use it to specify a set of functions that will handle the loading, saving, and other tasks associated with session handling.

You can use these functions to load session data from a database, or any other source you may want.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could catch the cookie sent by browser and select from table using session id from cookie, but most probably there is a better way to solve your problem.

Why can't you simply move the code into Yii controller? Even if it is something specific, it's usually easy to work around.